# Silverlight: Parent ViewModel Property value to Child ViewModel property

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I posted this question on the Silverlight forums, but haven't been able to get an answer to solve my issue, so I hope the guru's at SO can help!

Basically I have an entity property in my parent viewmodel.  When this entity changes I need the ID of the entity in my child viewmodel.  I have created a child control with a dependency property and created a binding in the constructor.  I am trying to implement all this using MVVM and MEF.

My ParentViewModel:

```
[ExportPlugin(ViewModelTypes.ParentViewModel, PluginType.ViewModel)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ParentViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private Person _currentPerson;
    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return _currentPerson; }
        private set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_currentPerson, value))
            {
                _currentPerson= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ParentUserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ParentUserControl" x:Name="ParentControl">
        <local:ChildUserControl PersonID="{Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Mode=TwoWay, Path=DataContext.CurrentPerson.ID}" />
</UserControl>
```

My ChildUserControl codebehind:

```
public partial class ChildUserControl : UserControl
{
    #region Private Properties
    private PluginCatalogService _catalogService = PluginCatalogService.Instance;
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonIDProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("PersonID", typeof(int), typeof(ChildUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnPersonIDChanged));
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PersonIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonIDProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public ChildUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            this.DataContext = _catalogService.FindPlugin(ViewModelTypes.ChildViewModel, PluginType.ViewModel);

        this.SetBinding(PersonIDProperty, new Binding("PersonID") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = DataContext, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
    }
    #endregion

private static void OnPersonIDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

My ChildViewModel:

```
[ExportPlugin(ViewModelTypes.ChildViewModel, PluginType.ViewModel)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ChildViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private int _personID;
    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return _personID; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_personID, value))
            {
                _personID= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PersonID");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created the `OnPersonIDChanged` event to see if when the `CurrentPerson` entity changed, the change was being picked up in the `ChildControl`, which it is.  It just isn't being picked up in the `ChildControl ViewModel`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably, if you are using PRISM you can use the EventAggregator...
see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) and https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Another option would be to hook (hack) onto the PropertyChanged

```
ViewModel1.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
   if (e.PropertyName == "XXX")
   {
      ViewModel2.PropertyX = vm1.PropertY;
   }
};
```